# Programmatically load .Net assembly with symbols

Tags: .net, mono, .net-assembly, system.reflection

I've got a C# tool that loads arbitary assemblies using `Assembly.LoadFrom()`. It then does some reflection on the assemblies and reports back to the user. The problem is there is no debugging information, so my tool can't report on line numbers or file names, for instance.

The assemblies I'm loading have symbol files in the same directory (they're mdb files, because I'm on OSX and using mono). How can I load these files and associate them with the relevant assemblies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the .mdb files should just work if they are located in the same directory as the dll files.

What you might be missing is the flag `--debug` passed to mono when launching your program.